# Arquillian Graphene/Drone tests use wrong port to access WebLogic managed server

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, jboss-arquillian, arquillian-drone, graphene2

I'm using Arquillian to perform integration tests for one of my projects and have found that when the application is deployed to a WebLogic 12c R2 container the wrong port number is being used by Arquillian Graphene/Drone to perform the browser tests. When the browser is launched by the test, the port assigned to the WebLogic Admin server is used rather than the port assigned the WebLogic Managed server, which means container returns an HTTP 404 error causing the test case to fail.

I've worked through the code for the various Arquillian components and I believe I've found the root cause of the problem. The problem appears to be in the [RESTUtils](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-container-wls/blob/master/wls-common/src/main/java/org/jboss/arquillian/container/wls/rest/RESTUtils.java) class of the "wls-common" module which contains the `deploy(CommonWebLogicConfiguration config, Logger logger, Archive<?> archive)` method which is responsible for deploying the archive to the WebLogic Managed server and returning the `ProtocolMetaData` back to Arquillian. The `ProtocolMetaData` is subsequently used by Arquillian Graphene/Drone to access the web page.

Within this method is the following line of code 
`HTTPContext httpContext = new HTTPContext(adminUrl.getHost(), adminUrl.getPort());` which used to build the `ProtocolMetaData` object. This means that the admin port is being used instead of the port assigned to the Managed server.

Assuming I've correctly identified the root cause, I don't believe that this Arquillian container adapter can be used with WebLogic 12c R2, which makes me think I might be trying to use this adapter incorrectly.

The Maven dependency for the WebLogic container adapter in my POM file is as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-wls-remote-rest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The entry in my arquillian.xml file is as follows:

```
<container qualifier="arquillian-weblogic-rest">
    <configuration>
        <property name="adminUrl">http://xxxx:7001</property>
        <property name="adminUserName">weblogic</property>
        <property name="adminPassword">xxxx</property>
        <property name="target">wls_server_1</property>
    </configuration>
    <protocol type="Servlet 3.0">
        <property name="host">xxxx</property>
        <property name="port">8080</property>
    </protocol>
</container>
```

The version of WebLogic I'm using is 12.2.1

**My question is** am I missing something in way I'm trying to use this container adapter to deploy to a WebLogic 12c R2 container? Is anyone else using this adapter successfully?

As the WebLogic container is running on a separate host, I believe I need to use the REST adapter rather than the remote adapter, as the remote adapter appears to require the Arquillian test to run on the same host as the WebLogic container.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you are running a test that should be run as a client in the server instead of as a client. By default all Arquillian tests will be run within the application server. The port you're seeing is being used because you have to use the admin URL to post a deployment to the server. You want your tests to be run outside of the server as a client, just like any other web browser.

There are three ways to run a test as a client:

1. Annotate the class with `@RunAsClient`, which will mark all tests as client tests.
2. Annotate a test with `@RunAsClient`, which as you would expect would only apply to that test.
3. Set the deployment to non-testable by using the `testable = false` property of the `@Deployment` annotation. Any tests referencing this deployment will be client tests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I've already got the annotation `@Deployment(testable = false)` on the method that creates Shrinkwrap deployment. Also the test case works fine if I deploy to a Glassfish or a Wildfly container, whereby Arquillian uses for admin port to upload the deployment and the normal HTTP port to run the test.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like a bug.